# Block use of older versions of illegally downloaded app (APK)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-console

I have a paid application that in the old version did not verify the license of the play store and I have now discovered that there are some sites that illegally download the APK from an old version where users can install and access my database in the firebase. (without paying for the download)

The database in firebase (realtime database) has already been blocked access through the rules, but as the app uses ***set persistent on*** then the fraudulent users are still using the app (I can see in firebase analytics) .

Any idea how to block old versions, or force these versions to not work to prevent these users from being able to use the app?

[image]

Comment: If disk persistence in the app is enabled, they'll only be able to access data that they've already downloaded. I don't think there's much Firebase can do, aside from what I mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50429782/how-to-block-users-by-app-version-in-firebase

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe if I create a new SHA-1 key for new users and remove the old key from firebase, will persistence continue to work or will it crash? Too risky to punish legitimate users?

Answer (score 1):

Store a data about your update in your firebase database. when a user opens your app then you should check that data to validate updated app. Sure u can do much more with logic. You can store version code as they are always unique.

Comment: I already use access rules that are blocking the read / update of the database of these versions, but because persistence is enabled, users who already have data previously downloaded continue to use the app. I would like to find some solution to prevent the use of these versions (crash) or to clean the database of these old versions.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that you need code in your app to do this, and once you have launched, you can't go back and change your code. For this app you are probably stuck.

In the future, using a product like [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) to have a "please update" switch in your app that you can control from the cloud is probably a good idea.

Comment: I agree and already use Firebase Remote Config in recent versions, I also use LicenseChecker from market_licensing (https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up), as well as access rules in realtime-database. Thanks for the answer.