# I would like android users to no longer be able to access the database

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

I have a problem with my android app, I would like to block it for a moment.
This app use Firebase with an another iOS app.
I would like android users to no longer be able to access the database for example

Comment: What do you mean by "block the Android users for a moment"? What exactly would you like to happen?

Comment: I would like android users to no longer be able to access the database for example

Comment: And how would you like to restrict that? Through security rules? Inside your application code?

Comment: With security rules by preference,

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built into Firebase security rules for blocking requests a specific platform, so you'd have to build it yourself on top of Firebase - similar to [Firebase Security Rules Block Writing to Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50430136).